# Get Output of stored procedure using PutSql in Nifi

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, groovy, apache-nifi, plsql-package

I have to get the output of Oracle stored procedure in Nifi.
I've tried PutSql with the following sql statement :

> declare out VARCHAR2 ; begin PKG_TEST.P_TEST(1,out); end;

It works fine but it just executes the script.
How can I get the value of output 'out' ?
Edit : I tried the Groovy script here :

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Does-ExecuteSQL-processor-allow-to-execute-stored-procedure/td-p/158922

I get the following error :

> 2022-06-17 13:38:53,353 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-9] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=26ab18f1-3b0c-18cf-d90b-3d5904676458] groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script6a6d0a35$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (String, String, java.sql.Date, null, String, null, null, String...) values: [xxxx, xxxx, 2022-05-30, null, OK, null, null, ...]: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script6a6d0a35$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (String, String, java.sql.Date, null, String, null, null, String...) values: [xxxx,xxxx, 2022-05-30, null, OK, null, null, ...]

> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:255)

So I have the output of procedure but I get the error !

Script :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.*
import groovy.sql.OutParameter
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.sql.ResultSet


////Get the session values from Nifi flow Start 
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
  String TYPE_NOTIFICATION = flowFile.getAttribute('TYPE_NOTIFICATION')
  String ID_NOTIFICATION = flowFile.getAttribute('ID_NOTIFICATION')
////Get the session values from Nifi flow END
 
 

String sqlString ="""{call PKG_TEST.P_TEST(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}""";

def parametersList = [ID_NOTIFICATION, TYPE_NOTIFICATION,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.DATE,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.VARCHAR,Sql.DATE ];
 
 
SQL.mydbxx.call(sqlString, parametersList) {out1, out2,...->
    flowFile.putAttribute("out1",out1)...
};

 

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Signature of my stored procedure :
[image]
[image]
Thank you!

Comment: I tried it but it didn't change anything . How am I supposed to use that variable later ? thank you

Comment: it's not possible yet to get output parameters in nifi for oracle database. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/I-am-Trying-to-invoke-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-nifi-How/td-p/196506
You could use groovyscript. some examples here: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.16.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/index.html

Comment: as soon as you testing approach `PKG_TEST.P_TEST` - you can use oracle table function instead of procedure and return output value through resultset.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an external database, I have to use that procedure 7. I think that the documentation ofputsql/exeutesql is incomplete when it comes to plsql...  I will use GroovyScript thx.

Answer (score 0):

i can't test it - so, it's just a reference code

use `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor

add `SQL.mydb` parameter on the level of processor and link it to required DBCP pool.

set approximately this as a script body

```js
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def statement = '''
  declare out VARCHAR2; 
  begin
    PKG_TEST.P_TEST(?, out);
  end;
  ? := out;
'''
//parameters for each ? placeholder
def params = [
  ff.param_input as Long, //get parameter value from flowfile attribute
  SQL.mydb.VARCHAR, //out varchar parameter https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#VARCHAR
]
SQL.mydb.call(statement, params){p_out-> //we have only one out patameter
    //closure to process output parameters
    ff.param_output = p_out //assign value into flowfile attribute
}

//transfer flowfile to success
REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: I added my script to the post , can you check it please ? in the error message I have the output of my stored procedure so the call is OK but I have an error ! thx

Comment: 1. what is the line number in error?
2. seems something wrong with `SQL.mydbxx.call(){}` - please show how it really looks

Comment: also i'm not sure all the parameters that you have provided as output in groovy declared as output in procedure - that's the most realistic issue.

Comment: yes they are all outputs (see image in the post) .

Comment: I tried : SQL.mydbxx.call(sqlString, parametersList) and I don't have the error, the problem is that when I iterate over the parametersList, I can't convert Sql.VARCHAR to String, so I'm unable to add the outputs as attributes to the flowfile . That's why I try to use the other method : 
call(String sql, List<Object> params, Closure closure) I don't have a line number in error message (error stack in the post) but the error is in the closure

Comment: you have mess with number of parameters. count of `?` in statement must correspond to number of objects in parameter list, and count of OUT parameters in stored procedure must correspond to number of parameters in closure. i don't see your real code - so i can't compare what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I had the wrong number of arguments ><'  it works fine now